# some $a_i, a_j,a_k$ are the sides of a triangle

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Suppose $a_1,...,a_6$ is a sequence of positive numbers such that
$$\max \{a_1,...,a_6\} \le 6 \min \{a_1,...,a_6\}$$
Show that there is some $i,j,k$ with $1\le i < j < k \le 6$ such that $a_i, a_j$ $a_k$ are the sides of a triangle.

This was a problem in a math olympiad Colombia, I couldn't do it and then realised that there was a harder version of it in $2012$ USAMO (and it´s rare since they show this is not a possible case).

I just wanted to show that there exists some $i,j,k$ with $1\le i < j < k \le 6$ such that $a_i + a_j > a_k$, and I did many things, but none of them worked.

Comment: I don't think this holds for all sequences, since the sequence $1,1,1,1,1,6$ follows these conditions, but $1$, $1$, and $6$ are not sides of a triangle. Are there any other restrictions?

Comment: @IsaacBrowne "there is some $i,k,k$". Hence your counterxample does not work

Comment: @leonbloy Yes, the question was just edited. Now it is better!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have a sequence $a_1,...,a_6$ of positive numbers such that

- $\max\{a_1,...,a_6\}\le 6\min\{a_1,...,a_6\}$.$\\[4pt]$

  For all $i,j,k$ with $1\le i < j < k \le 6$, the numbers $a_i,a_j,a_k$ are not the sides of a triangle.

Our goal is to derive a contradiction.

Without loss of generality, assume
$$a_1\le a_2 \le a_3\le a_4\le a_5\le a_6$$

By hypothesis, we have $a_6 \le 6a_1$.

Then we get
\begin{align*}
a_2&\ge a_1\\[4pt]
a_3&\ge a_2 + a_1\ge a_1 + a_1=2a_1\\[4pt]
a_4&\ge a_3 + a_2\ge 2a_1+a_1=3a_1\\[4pt]
a_5&\ge a_4+a_3\ge 3a_1+2a_1=5a_1\\[4pt]
a_6&\ge a_5 + a_4\ge 5a_1+3a_1=8a_1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so we have $6a_1\!\ge a_6\ge 8a_1,\;$contradiction.

Comment: A note to add: This technique can be generalized to show that for any nondecreasing sequence of positive reals $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ so no distinct $i,j,k$ have $a_i,a_j,a_k$ forming a triangle, $a_n\geq F_na_1$ where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number. This is sufficient to solve the 2012 USAMO problem.

Comment: I haven't seen the solution to that USAMO problem yet, but I had seen that $ n \geq 13$ but how could it be if you start getting a contradiction from $n=6$

Comment: @Vmimi: The USAMO problem asks about _acute_ triangles. Your problem has no such restriction.

Comment: @Vmimi: As regards the USAMO problem, here's a link: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2012_USAMO_Problems/Problem_1